# What's the difference between `transaction and `transaction`event in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, register-transfer-level, vlsi

I understand that `event is when the signal *transitions* to/from a value.` transaction is when a signal is assigned a value, even if the value is the same as the previous value.

My question is what is `transaction`event? Does it mean that -both- a transaction and an event has taken place on a signal or does it mean that either a transaction has taken place OR an event has taken place on the given signal. Is it an AND of transaction and event or is it an OR?

Thanks.

Comment: The format in the post does not seem to work. I meant `transaction and `event combined.

Comment: The reason the 'format' didn't work is that you were using back ticks instead of apostrophes to describe attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The `'transaction` attribute is a signal of type `bit` that toggles on every assignment to a signal. Hence, because every signal can create a `'event`, `'transaction'event` simply occurs on every transaction, or signal assignment.

`'event` is a function that returns a `boolean` when signal has changed value.

Comment: Thanks much, Tricky. To make sure I understand; If there is a 'transaction on a signal, 'transaction'event will occur OR if there is a 'event on a signal, 'transaction'event will occur. It is not necessary that both 'transaction and 'event need to occur at the same time, to make 'transaction'event occur.

Comment: Transaction will toggle on every assignment,  even if the signal is assigned the same value over and over. Assigning the same value will not cause an event.